# How to store the result from loop into the variable or the list

Tags: python-3.x

I have the code below that runs on the active excel sheet to check specified cells.
If the specified cell shows "Fail", it will print out the failed person and the time.

```
import xlwings as xw
import xlrd

def check_result():
    sheet = xw.books.active.sheets.active
    for x in range(1, 5): 
        if sheet['B' + str(x)].value =="Fail":
            print(sheet['A' + str(x)].value, xlrd.xldate_as_datetime(sheet['C' + str(x)].value, 0))

check_result()
```

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tERx.png)
How can I save this printed result into the variable or the list?
The excel file (.xlsm) is connecting to the third party software, and this file needs to be opened to generate the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the print statement, it looks like that there are three outputs. You can have a list or tuple to save the printed data like this.

**With List**

```
List = []
List.append([sheet['A' + str(x)].value, xlrd.xldate_as_datetime(sheet['C' + str(x)].value, 0])
```

NOTE: define List outside of your for loop.

Let me know if there is any problem with the code.

Comment: It worked.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted. Thanks